# Bash, change a file name based on a known keyword in a script

Tags: bash, rename

I need to change a file name in a script based on a known keyword.

For example, file `keywords.root.T127C` should be renamed `keywords_environment.root.T127C`.

I tried to use this command:

```
find . -name $keywords* | sed -e "p"
```

which output: `./current_directory/keywords.root.T127C` but I have no idea to assign it to a variable, `$var`. If it can be assigned, I know how to trim it with the command like:

```
echo "${var##*.}".
```

My questions:

(1) Is there efficient way to do it with only one command? Saying, converting "keywords.root.T127C" directly to "keywords_environment.root.T127C" ?

(2) If no to (1), how can I assign the "./current_directory/keywords.root.T127C" to a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a best-practices implementation (for recursive use; use cases can use globs rather than `find` are simpler) -- using a NUL-delimited stream of filenames, and thus being safe even with unusual names (such as those containing literal newlines):

```
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  [[ $filename = *.* ]] \
    && mv -- "$filename" "${filename%%.*}_environment.${filename#*.}"
done < <(find . -name "${keyword}*" -print0)
```

See also [BashFAQ #30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030).

Comment: +1 for using/showing most efficient way to use find's output.

Comment: @Charles, Thanks for your solution and the link! Unfortunately, our server is out of work temporarily(at least hopefully it's a temporary down), therefore I can't run your solution before it backs to normal. I'll post my feedback here when there is any result.

Comment: The server has no possibility to be recovered before next Thursday ! I really wanna kill somebody !

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`:

```
for i in $(find . -name "$keyword*"); do
  nn="$(echo -n "$i" | sed 's/\(.*'$keyword'\)\(.*\)/\1_environment\2/g')"
  mv -- "$i" "$nn"
done
```

This changes `./keywords.root.T127C` to `./keywords_environment.root.T127C`.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if find's output includes filenames with spaces, filenames with glob characters with possible expansions, etc.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 (which, while it's titled in reference to `ls`, discusses misuses of `find` as well).

Comment: Entry #2 on the BashPitfalls page applies as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful resource, I am aware that this is not best practice, but the `sed` expression can be adjusted easily and from what the OP wrote, it might actually suffice like this. And seriously, who on earth uses spaces in their filenames???

Comment: "Who on Earth"? You're aware than Mac OS is a UNIX, right, and that spaces are used in filenames **all the time** there? And it's not just the `sed` expression that makes spaces dangerous and needs to be corrected.

Comment: Also: Think about security. You don't want to have done this wrong when someone malicious makes a filename called `$'/tmp/foo \n/etc/passwd'`, and your cleanup script goes through the list of files line-by-line deciding what to `rm`.

Comment: Also, it's not exactly unheard of to have a C program with a buffer overflow or similar bug creating a file with garbage in its filename. Handling the unexpected is part of writing good software.

Comment: Better, but still not fixed -- the `for i in $(find ...)` approach is inherently broken. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind, particularly sections 5 and later.

Comment: Thank you for all the input and the valuable insight. I will definitely try to use an approach like yours more often as of now and will have a closer look at the Pitfalls discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot especially to Charles !
I modified a little bit to his post to adopt my application :

1. I changed the file name search to "./sno*.root.T127C"
2. I added a line of "newfilename" to remove the "./" part of a filename.

Here is the whole code works well for me.

And Hopefully it's useful to other potential guys either.

```
env_str="_environment."
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  [[ $filename = ./sno*.root.T127C ]] \
    && newfilename="${filename#./}" \
    && mv -- "$newfilename" "${newfilename%%.*}${env_str}${newfilename#*.}"
done < <(find . -name "${keyword}*" -print0)
```

Comment: Glad this helped! If you don't mind, I'll edit this answer to fix the indentation. Does the `./` matter, if all you're doing is passing it to mv?

Comment: Yes, I actually only need the file name after the "./" since I need to "play" further for the file name.

Comment: In that case, you can replace the `-print0` which `-printf '%P\0'` to not have any leading `./` in the first place.

Comment: By the way, you might also consider `find . '(' -name "${keyword}*" -a -name "sno*.root.T127C" ')' -printf '%P\0'` to apply both filters inside `find`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, replacing `-print0` with `-printf '%p'\0` works well. But the line of `&& newfilename="${filename#./}" \` is still necessary(I thought is not necessary, but that doesn't work.).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the `find ...` command you suggested doesn't work well. It only prints a file with its original name ...

Comment: Actually, there're a couple of questions I'd like to ask: (1)How the `${keyword}` has been assigned ? there is no clear assignment in commands. (2)the double "<" after "done" are separated by a space, why in this shape ?  Thanks !

Comment: `%p\0` and `%P\0` are two different things. Please be exact. As for the assignment -- that's your job, to do that first. As for the `< <(...)`, `<` is the operator to redirect from a file, and `<( )` is the operator to connect a subshell via a named FD (or, on some platforms, a named pipe), which looks and acts as a file.